# C# run process.start in X seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like some help please, I have the following code:

```
private void strtGameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("test.exe");
    this.Close();
}
```

How can I run the `test.exe` after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding any other problem

```
private async void strtGameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strtGameBtn.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Process.Start("test.exe");
    this.Close();
}
```

or more likely, depending on what you want to the form to do

```
private void strtGameBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => 
      {
         Thread.Sleep(5000);
         Process.Start("test.exe");
      });
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: That first method should be async to use await